# How would you limit the number of operations per second?

Tags: c#, .net

How would you limit the number of operations per second?

Lets say we have to copy files from one location to another and we don't want more than 5 files to be processed per second.

Please see what I am doing

```
private static string currentStamp;
private static int processedInCurrentStamp = 0;

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    currentStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}");
    Run();
}

private static void Run()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Int32.MaxValue; i++)
    {
        string s = DateTime.Now.ToString("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}");
        if (currentStamp.Equals(s))
        {
            if (processedInCurrentStamp < 5)
            {
                ProcessItem();
                processedInCurrentStamp++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ::: {1}", currentStamp, processedInCurrentStamp);
            currentStamp = s;
            processedInCurrentStamp = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

But I need a more elegant and bullet proof way.

Comment: It seems that no tasks are processed synchronously in your code, just sequential executions.

Comment: @Denny; yes these are sequential operations.

Comment: @Danny Chen: Hm... That's what synchronously means...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get the starting time, and then in the loop calculate the maximum number of files that should be processed up to the current time, and sleep if you are ahead:

```
DateTime start = DateTime.UtcNow;

int i = 1;
while (i <= 100) {

  int limit = (int)((DateTime.UtcNow - start).TotalSeconds * 5.0);

  if (i <= limit) {

    Console.WriteLine(i);
    i++;

  } else {
    Thread.Sleep(100);
  }

}
```

This way the code will catch up if some operations take longer. If you only get three operations one second, it can do seven the next second.

Note that I am using `UtcNow` instead of `Now` to avoid the nasty jump in time that happens twice a year.

#### Edit:

Another alternative is to measure the time that an operation takes, and sleep the rest of it's time slot:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++ ) {

  DateTime start = DateTime.UtcNow;

  Console.WriteLine(i);

  int left = (int)(start.AddSeconds(1.0 / 5.0) - DateTime.UtcNow).TotalMilliseconds;
  if (left > 0) {
    Thread.Sleep(left);
  }

}
```

Comment: well, i need to do MAX of 5 operations per second. Don't want to catch up if an operation took longer in last second. Btw, what does this line do? 
int limit = (int)((DateTime.UtcNow - start).TotalSeconds * 5.0);

Comment: @Sumee: I added an alternative above that might fit you better. The limit that is calculated is the number of operations that should have been done from the start to the current time. If three seconds have passed, the limit will be 15.

Answer (score 5):

I would make a simple method that processes five files at a time and call that every second using a timer.

Comment: Brian, its a great idea but I really can't do this because I don't know the items upfront. It's like a queue and I just process them as they come.

Answer (score 4):

Use a token bucket:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket

Answer (score 4):

Sumee

You could use a throttled producer/ consumer queue. It would have a background thread which runs at an interval, processing your file. You could enqueue the file names as they arrive and the throttled dequeue action (Action) would dequeue.  Here is an example of what I mean:

```
    public class ThrottledQueue<T> : IDisposable where T : class
{
    readonly object _locker = new object();
    readonly List<Thread> _workers;
    readonly Queue<T> _taskQueue = new Queue<T>();
    readonly Action<T> _dequeueAction;
    readonly TimeSpan _throttleTimespan;
    readonly Thread _workerThread;
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SuperQueue{T}"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="millisecondInterval">interval between throttled thread invokation</param>
    /// <param name="dequeueAction">The dequeue action.</param>
    public ThrottledQueue(int millisecondInterval, Action<T> dequeueAction)
    {
        _dequeueAction = dequeueAction;

        // Create and start a separate thread for each worker
        _workerThread = new Thread(Consume) { IsBackground = true, Name = string.Format("ThrottledQueue worker") };
        _workerThread.Start();
        _throttleTimespan = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,millisecondInterval);

    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Enqueues the task.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="task">The task.</param>
    public void EnqueueTask(T task)
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            _taskQueue.Enqueue(task);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Consumes this instance.
    /// </summary>
    void Consume()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            T item = default(T);
            lock (_locker)
            {
                Monitor.Wait(_locker, _throttleTimespan);
                if (_taskQueue.Count != 0) 
                    item = _taskQueue.Dequeue();
            }
            if (item == null) return;

            // run actual method
            _dequeueAction(item);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs application-defined tasks associated with freeing, releasing, or resetting unmanaged resources.
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Enqueue one null task per worker to make each exit.
        EnqueueTask(null);

        _workerThread.Join();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that while you are trying to limit the number of items processed to 500 per second, the code above still runs a tight loop, thus putting a load on the CPU even when not processing a file.

If you want a real throttling, you have to change your logic to be timer- or event-driven, or use one of the Wait* methods to idle your process while waiting for the next opportunity to do some work.