# Is it possible to limit the number of web request per second?

Tags: c#, webrequest

Hi i am spidering the site and reading the contents.I want to keep the request rate reasonable. Up to approx 10 requests per second should probably be ok.Currently it is 5k request per minute and it is causing security issues as this looks to be a bot activity.
How to do this? Here is my code

```
protected void Iterareitems(List<Item> items)
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        GetImagesfromItem(item);

        if (item.HasChildren)
        {
            Iterareitems(item.Children.ToList());
        }
    }
}

protected void GetImagesfromItem(Item childitems)
{
    var document = new HtmlWeb().Load(completeurl);
    var urls = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
                .Select(e => e.GetAttributeValue("src", null))
                .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728569/how-to-limit-method-usage-per-amount-of-time

Comment: `it is causing security issues as this looks to be a bot activity`... it doesn't *looks to be a bot activity*, it **is** a bot activity :-)

Answer (score 4):

You need [System.Threading.Semaphore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore(v=vs.110).aspx), using which you can control the max concurrent threads/tasks. Here is an example:

```
var maxThreads = 3;
var semaphore = new Semaphore(maxThreads, maxThreads);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)    //10 tasks in total
{
    var j = i;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        semaphore.WaitOne();
        Console.WriteLine("start " + j.ToString());
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("end " + j.ToString());
        semaphore.Release();
    });
}
```

You can see at most 3 tasks are working, others are pending by `semaphore.WaitOne()` because the maximum limit reached, and the pending thread will continue if another thread released the semaphore by `semaphore.Release()`.